# Does a Collection<T> wrap an IList<T> or enumerate over the IList<T>?

Tags: c#

If I am exposing a internal member via a Collection property via:

```
public Collection<T> Entries
{
    get { return new Collection<T>(this.fieldImplimentingIList<T>); }
}
```

When this property is called what happens?  For example what happens when the following lines of code are called:

```
T test = instanceOfAbove.Entries[i];
instanceOfAbove[i] = valueOfTypeT;
```

It's clear that each time this property is called a new reference type is created but what acctually happens?  Does it simply wrap the `IList<T>` underneath, does it enumerate over the `IList<T>` and to create a new `Collection<T>` instance?  I'm concerned about performance if this property is used in a `for` loop.

Comment: `Collection<T>` wraps the `IList<T>`. Why are you returning it as a Collection<T>? Why not expose it as an IEnumerable<T>? Are you trying to prevent modification to the underlying list?

Comment: Thanks for the question! I haven't thought Collection is just a wrapper over list ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Reflector, the new `Collection<T>` just wraps the `IList<T>`:

```
public Collection(IList<T> list)
{
    if (list == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.list);
    }
    this.items = list;
}
```

And from [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132401.aspx):

> Initializes a new instance of the Collection<(Of <(T>)>) class
>   **as a wrapper** for the specified list.

(emphasis added)

So the overhead is minimal (the list is not enumerated), and changes to the returned collection will affect the original list.

(By the way, I am assuming you are referring to `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>` -- there isn't a generic version of Collection in the top-level System.Collections namespace.)

Comment: You're right, about the namespace. My mistake.  I edited the question title.

Answer (score 2):

According to Reflector - here is constructor of the Collection:

```
public Collection(IList<T> list)
{
    if (list == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.list);
    }
    this.items = list;
}
```

So as you can see Collection wraps IList and no data is copied.